# QT Creator Build Error: failure during conversion to COFF

Tags: qt, qt-creator

error: LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

I'am getting this error every time I try to build any project on my Qt Creator.
I have VS2010 installed and the compiler version set to MSVC C++ compiler 10.0(x86).
I have Qt 5.2.1 MSVC2010 32bit OpenGL.

Comment: Have you seen [this link](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24507)? Install the SP1 of VS2010 could solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error appears because you have installed VS 2012 after you have actually installed VS 2010 in your system.

It can be solved if you install SP1 for VS2010.

An other solution is to go to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cvtres.exe

and check the version of cvtres.exe. If the date is 03/18/2010 go to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\cvtres.exe

and copy cvtres.exe then replace it On

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cvtres.exe

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot it worked by installing service pack 1

Comment: Confirmed, your alternative solution worked.  To clairfy, **the VC 11.0 version must replace the VC 10.0 version**.  Your answer was vague to me and I thought you were describing the opposite.

Comment: &Nick Miller Yeah, you are right. It was a vague and I modified it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur when.Net Framework updated to 4.5.x. To resolve this error

1. You can change project properties as "Enable Incremental Linking -> "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)".
2. Or, uninstall the .Net Framework 4.5.x and install .NET Framework 4.